# How to combine two dataframes with different shapes on multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Thank you in advance for your time and effort to answer. I'm trying to **combine two dataframes (one containing current data, the other containing future prediction data) with different shapes**.

For example,

```
df1 = ['Date', 'ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC', 'GroupNumber']

df2 = ['Date', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'GroupNumber']
```

where df1 has a shape of (3000, 5) and df2 has a shape of (5000, 5).

I want to combine these two dataframes on the same 'Date' and 'GroupNumber' column values.

In the end, it would look something like :

```
final_df = ['Date', 'ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC','Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'GroupNumber'] with the shape of (5000, 8)
```

Since df1 is smaller than df2, some rows will be empty when combined.

Of course, these shape is just an arbitrary number I came up with as an example. I've tried

```
final_df = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='_actual', rsuffix='_prediction', on='GroupNumber','Date')
```

But this didn't exactly work. If anyone has a suggestion, i'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: What about `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Comment: I need to combine the two dfs, which have different shapes. So simply concatenating didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas `merge` to perform a `left join`:

```
import pandas as pd
final_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['GroupNumber','Date'],how='left')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. When I try the code you suggested, i get this: "ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"

Comment: Sounds like one of your date column is of datetime type and the other isn’t. Make sure they have the same type prior to the merge.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!